# EXTADT in libextobjc

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, macros, cocoapods

So I'm trying use this library in my iOS app using objective-c:

https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTADT.h

which is included in the `libextobjc` package, installable via cocoapods.  Say I create some ADT and name this "SomeADT.h".  I just basically follow the example in the documentation.

Say I include `SomeADT.h` in `SomeFile1.m` and use it.  It compiles fine.

For some reason, however, when I include `SomeADT.h` also in `SomeFile2.m`, it gives me an error of this sort:

> duplicate symbol _SomeADT in:
>       /Users/.../SomeFile1.o
>       /Users/.../SomeFile2.o ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

The `SomeADT.h` file has `ifndef` macro etc., why would it still complain about this?  I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious here.  For reference, I don't have a `SomeADT.c` file, but it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: post sources for SomeFile1 and SomeFile2 please